# Reading from a file with delimiters and saving into an object c++

Tags: c++

I'm writing a program for a beginner c++ class that will read strings from a file and store them into an object which will be in a vector. The file uses ',' as a delimiter and have whitespaces within the strings. I have it working using a bunch of getlines, but I am wondering if there is a way to clean up the code or possibly optimize it.

```
    while getline(ifs,s){
    string stream ss(s);
       getline(ss,str1,',');
       getline(ss,str2,',');
       getline(ss,str3,',');
    //I take these variables and pushback onto a vector using the object's
    //constructor
    }
```

I currently have something like that, but I was wondering if theres a better way to do it. I been looking into overloading extraction operators, but I think I run into the issue of not being able to overload the whitespace delimiter for >>

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you would use a tokenizer for this. boost.tokenizer is great, but for a beginner C++ class, you'll probably want to go with strtok() http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtok

Tokenize your input data using strtok() and then loop over the tokens.